# How to do multiboxplot for a single variable based on bins from cut function in r?

Tags: r, visualization, boxplot, binning

I am trying to create a **multibox plot** for a variable **based on number of bins from cut function**

```
movie_reg %>% select(Collection) %>% pull() %>% cut(7) 

[1] (3.57e+04,4.86e+04] (3.57e+04,4.86e+04] (6.14e+04,7.43e+04] (6.14e+04,7.43e+04] (6.14e+04,7.43e+04]
  [6] (4.86e+04,6.14e+04] (3.57e+04,4.86e+04] (3.57e+04,4.86e+04] (2.29e+04,3.57e+04] (3.57e+04,4.86e+04]
 [11] (2.29e+04,3.57e+04] (3.57e+04,4.86e+04] (3.57e+04,4.86e+04] (3.57e+04,4.86e+04] (3.57e+04,4.86e+04]
.
.
[501] (2.29e+04,3.57e+04] (3.57e+04,4.86e+04] (3.57e+04,4.86e+04] (3.57e+04,4.86e+04] (3.57e+04,4.86e+04]
[506] (3.57e+04,4.86e+04]
7 Levels: (9.91e+03,2.29e+04] (2.29e+04,3.57e+04] (3.57e+04,4.86e+04] (4.86e+04,6.14e+04] ... (8.71e+04,1e+05]
```

I am not sure how exactly I will pass levels and corresponding values to it in boxplot. Below is what I have tried but getting error:

```
movie_reg %>% select(Collection) %>% pull() %>% cut(7) %>% boxplot(aes(x=levels))
```

```
Error in sort.int(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing, ...) : 'x' must be atomic
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mixed up `boxplot()` from base R with `geom_boxplot()` from ggplot2. In any case, if your question is about visualization the categories obtained from `cut()`, you can add the column using:

```
movie_reg = data.frame(Collection = runif(100))
movie_reg %>% mutate(levels = cut(Collection,7))
```

Use boxplot:

```
boxplot(Collection ~ levels,data=movie_reg %>% mutate(levels = cut(Collection,7)),horizontal=TRUE,las=2,cex.axis=0.6)
```

[image]

Or ggplot2 :

```
movie_reg %>% mutate(levels = cut(Collection,7)) %>% ggplot(aes(x=levels,y=Collection)) + geom_boxplot() + coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @StupidWolf for presenting the examples perfectly. I did mix up on base plot & ggplot and also I was not mutating so wasn't getting both x, y inputs for the plot. Also split function came in handy for this type of plotting as it retains both values and groups.

```{r}
movie_reg %>% 
select(Collection) %>% 
pull() %>% 
split(f = c(0,20000,40000,60000,80000,100000)) %>% 
boxplot()
```

Comment: you are basically manually assigning the groups to the rows by using split like that.. why pass it through 4 or 5 pipes when 1 command will do?

Comment: I am new to r and just exploring how can I achieve the distribution comparison. Seems like `split` doesn't have option to group the values by mentioning number of bins. If that's the case then I will be using `cut function`. Thanks again for helping !

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you provide a reproducible example, now it is very difficult to help you. I do notice that you are using aesthetics in the boxplot function, but aesthetics are part of ggplot, not the base function `boxplot()`. Also, in a multi boxplot, you need to supply x and y, so maybe you just want a bar chart showing the count per group (which only needs an x)?

```
movie_reg %>% 
  select(Collection) %>% 
  pull() %>% 
  cut(7) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=levels)) + 
  geom_bar()
```

Comment: thanks that was useful. What I was trying to achieve is actually easy with `split function` and I have just implemented the same with code:
```{r}
movie_reg %>% select(Collection) %>% pull() %>% range()

movie_reg %>% 
select(Collection) %>% 
pull() %>% 
split(f = as.factor(c(0,20000,40000,60000,80000,100000))) %>% 
boxplot()
```